# Linux rename with replacement

Tags: linux, bash

So there is a program called [Filebot](https://www.filebot.net/) which you can input a directory and from there you can choose from a few databases to match on. End result is a cleanly renamed and often a media server approved format.

My goal is to just run it from bash and not involve third parties regardless of accuracy.

I've been able to use rename to get rid of XXX and replace with  but in the end I get stuck with .... or ... or some other variation ( spaces, brackets, etc...). Is it possible to run as one rename or do I need to separate instances of rename to clean up my issue?

I understand the code reflected is in test only mode as I don't want to rename anything without being sure yet.

Please no spoiler answers but rather a pointer. I'm happy to dig further if necessary I just don't need to be fed a final answer.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name "*.*" -exec rename -n 's/"  "|"-YTS.LT|YTS.LT|1080p|720p|BRrip|BluRay|x264|AAC|WEBRip|YTS.AG|YTS.MX|YTS.AM|Deceit|-|BOKUTOX|YIFY|BrRip|\[|]//ig' {} \;
```

sample output after the inital run

```
rename(./Dick Tracy (1990) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.LT]/Dick.Tracy.1990.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.LT].mp4, ./Dick Tracy (1990)   /Dick.Tracy.1990....mp4)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the search pattern for each name match to include optional matches (`?` after term) on the unnecessary dots / brackets and spaces. Try this pattern format inside a pair of the `|` delimiter :

```
[\[ \.-]+?(720p|BluRay)\]?
```

Add   `+` to spot double spaces, and `YTS\...` to match anything format `YTS.` plus 2 characters.

Putting those together into your existing expression would help you to your next step which is to clean up the other terms and filters:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name "*.*" -exec rename -n 's/"  "|"|  +|[\[ \.-]+?(YTS\...|720p|BluRay|x264)\]?|-//ig'

rename(Dick Tracy (1990)  [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.LT]/Dick.Tracy.1990.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.LT].mp4, Dick Tracy (1990)/Dick.Tracy.1990.mp4)
```

See handy information on [Regular Expressions](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).